# How to inherit property values from a parent pom

Tags: maven, inheritance, properties

I know this should be trivial (even default behavior) but it is NOT working.  I found some *similar* inheritance topics but none specific to inheriting elements of the properties tag.

- Parent property defined as myprop.version.  In the parent I could access the version as ${myprop.version}.
- Child using the version number directly works fine.  Child using ${myprop.version} totally breaks maven.

What am I misunderstanding?   Can this be fixed?

In parent (bom-pom-master project) POM:

```
<properties>
  <myprop.version>2.6.3</myprop.version>
</properties>
```

In Child POM:

```
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${myprop.version}</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

NOTE:  Only *some* of my projects need the spring-boot-maven-plugin, so it seems to me that it should NOT be included in the parent.  Am I wrong?

EDIT:  As requested I am adding below the full parent and child POMs "as they were" before attempting inheritance.

**Parent** inherited by every project, NOT JUST those that need the spring-boot-maven-plugin, so any change must still work with every type of project, from library JAR, self-running Spring Boot JAR apps with Tomcat embedded, REST webapp WAR apps that are deployed to a Tomcat server (this particular child), and full webapps deployed to a Tomcat server.  All of those are inheriting from this master bom pom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>net.domain</groupId>
  <artifactId>bom-pom-master</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>bom-pom-master</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <commons.io.version>2.11.0</commons.io.version>
    <commons.lang.version>3.12.0</commons.lang.version>
    <commons.text.version>1.9</commons.text.version>
    <httpclient.version>4.5.13</httpclient.version>
    <jackson.version>2.12.5</jackson.version>
    <jaxb.version>2.3.1</jaxb.version>
    <jjwt.version>0.9.1</jjwt.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
    <servlet.version>4.0.1</servlet.version>
    <spring.version>5.3.15</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>5.6.1</spring-security.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- apache commons -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>${commons.io.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>${commons.lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
      <version>${commons.text.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4j -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JJWT, library to add JWT bearer token support -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson JSON -->
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- server -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>${servlet.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- junit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
            <debug>true</debug>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

**Child** REST WAR pom that gets deployed on Tomcat.  The critical element is at the bottom where version is specified as 2.6.3.  In Eclipse that tag is not needed but for some reason it is essential to IntelliJ.  The failure that prompted this post was when I defined a property containing this value in the parent and tried to use it as ${my.version} in  place of 2.6.3 in the child.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>net.domain</groupId>
  <artifactId>rest-db-common</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>rest-db-common</name>
  <description>Common Services DB REST service</description>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- starters -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Our library(ies) -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.domain</groupId>
      <artifactId>core-lib</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.domain</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-db-common-api</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MsSQL -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>net.domain</groupId>
        <artifactId>bom-pom-master</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Properties are automatically inherited. The error must be somewhere else. Show us the whole POMs.

Comment: first you should define a plugin in a pluginManagement in your parent. (no need for a property) and any child project will use it.. No need for a property... and as @JFabianMeier already asked please show the full pom files (or at least a full working example project setup on github or alike)...

Comment: @Fabian:  Whole POMs added.   The new property was added in parent properties just like the other version properties, andattempted to reference it as ${newProperty} instead of 2.6.3 in child and it was not recognized.  @ khmarbaise: I fear that defining the plugin in the parent would interfere with children projects that don't use it.  Would it make sense to create an intermediate POM project for those that do use it?  This intermediate would be a child of the original parent and parent to the original child.  Does that make sense or am I being absurd?